# How to Ask page doesn't correctly encode the question typed in the search field

Tags: bug, status-completed, asking-questions, url-encoding

The [How to Ask page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask/advice) doesn't correctly URL encode the string typed in the search field. For example, if someone types "Objects in C++" in the search field and then clicks on the "proceed »" link below, they are redirected to this URL:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask?title=Objects%20in%20C++

Now on the top field of the new page, the title of the question shows up as "Objects in C  " (!). Obviously, the `title` of the previous form is not correctly URL encoded, as the + sign should become `%2B` in the URL (I'd suggest using `encodeURIComponent` in JavaScript for this purpose). Apparently, the problem involves other StackExchange sites too, not just SO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixed in the next build, presumably build rev 2013.12.9.1736 on meta and 2013.12.9.1208 on sites.